# QGIS custom grid / line oriented point displacement?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to sort point symbols at the same coordinates in a line. The first picture shows how I want it to be (all symbols in a single horizontal line), the second how it looks with the standard grid-based point displacement (multiple, unwanted rows of symbols, and therefor also an unwanted overlap of text and symbols).

Is there any way/plugin to either change the parameters of how the grid is built (number of rows/lines) or any other way to show symbols in a line?

I am not hugely into scripting or programming though.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE, Tyak! Please keep in mind, that from a cartographical point of view this display of information is not desirable, since the exact location of the ruins can not be determined.

Comment: I agree that this is not an exact map, but since most of the stuff I am showing is only known from literature anyways I don't think that it'd matter much.

Also: You gotta do what the boss wants you to do, so...^^

Comment: Sometimes telling your boss, that their ideas are bollocks, is the better solution ;-) could you tell some more about your data? Are the ruins all in one shape file? Are they separate points for each location, or do you have one point per city/site and then attributes?

Comment: they are all different points with the same coordinates on the same shape file.

Comment: I could put them into single points with attributes too if that woud help...

Answer (score 3):

I would calculate offset distance (`dx`) for each feature, so that I can position them by `(x, y) = ($x+dx, $y)`.

[image]

An example of expression to calculate `dx` is:

```
with_variable('my_array', array_agg("symbols", group_by:="geom_to_wkt($geometry)"), 
               5 *(array_find(@my_array, "symbols") - floor(array_length(@my_array)/2)))
```

- You will need to modify `"symbols"` according to your attribute field which defines your categorized symbols.
- The second line has a factor `5`, but it is arbitrary. Please adjust this number by visually checking your output.

---

[EDIT]

To modify x-location of symbols according to the `dx` calculated above, there would be some options:

(Option 1) **Geometry generator**

This is dynamic way, and probably a preferred option. In the `Layer Properties` window, click on <kbd>Change</kbd> button next to `Symbol`. Then select **Geometry generator** as the `Symbol layer type` and **Point/Multipoint** as the `Geometry type`. The actual expression would be `make_point($x+"dx", $y)`.

[image]

(Option 2) **Create points layer from table**

This tool is found under `Processing Toolbox | Vector creation`. It is more static way and requires `new_x` field (by `$x+"dx"`) and `new_y` field (`$y`, so it is not new). One merit of this approach is that you can later modify `new_x` and `new_y` field manually, so that you can place them in two or three rows if you like.

[image]

Comment: But wouldn't that give every symbol a fixed position? Wouldn't that result in gaps between symbols if some weren't there at a location?

Comment: @Tyak the `array_length` part counts the number of your symbols and `array_find` checks its position in the array. If you have many symbols the array is extended.

Comment: I am a bit embarrassed to admit, but it seems I'm too stupid to get the formula for the position in your very first paragraph ((x, y) = ($x+dx, $y)) working. When I copy it into the symbol style offset formula edit thingy I get an invalid expression message...

Comment: Thanks @Tyak I think some of functions take arguments differently when directly used in Layer Properties. As a test, please change `group_by:="geom_to_wkt($geometry)"` to `group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry)` ( remove double quotation marks ) and see if it works.

Comment: oh no, you might have misunderstood me (or I wasn't clear enough about my problem). I can't figure out how to insert any kind of formula into the feature positions. the "dx"-generation worked fine. but I can't find where/how to put the offset into the points! (and also thank you very much for your patience ; ))

Comment: Ah, sorry @Tyak I've forgotten that part. Edited my answer to add some possible options. There are merits and demerits in each approach. Hope any of them works for your case.

Comment: Thank you so very much, @Kazuhito!
I got the solution you provided working as intended, though I wasn't entirely satisfied with the offset being a true distance and therefor being scale dependand.

With the help of a colleague I was able to put the offset value (dx) into the offset calculator for each point with the formula
`concat(  to_string( "dx"), ',', to_string(0) )`
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Add extra points at each location to expand the grid layout** until the original point symbols fit on a single line of the grid.

Make the extra points invisible by setting the opacity of their symbol to 0%.

In this example I had 5 points at one location. I added another 16 points to expand the grid to 5x5, forcing the main 5 points onto the same line. I left the grid lines on so you can see the layout.

[image]

---

Note: Leave the attributes of the duplicate points blank, so you don't later get confused and think they represent real-world features. It's probably best to make a backup of the point file.

Comment: This seems to be a very easy and quick workaround, although it could become a bit confusing with the exponentially growing number of blank points. Thank you anyways. I will keep this trick in mind!